# Print all names from ManyToManyField except one in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have to write a query to print all the names inside the `ManyToManyField` except my own. The model is like this:

#### models.py

```
class Chat(models.Model):

room_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
creator= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="owner")
chatting_to= models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="chatting_to", null=True)
messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message, blank=True)
```

In each `Chat` object there are two users in the `ManyToManyField` `chatting_to` field, one is the current user and other is the person he's chatting with. I have to print the list of all the users that he's chatting with. My current approach is this `chat= Chat.objects.filter(chatting_to= request.user)` and I'm printing all the chatting_to users for each object inside the template. But with this one I'm getting my user object with that second one too which is inside the `ManyToManyField`. How to print all the users in the `chatting_to` `ManytoManyField` excluding the authenticated user.
EDIT:

```
chat= Chat.objects.filter(chatting_to= request.user)
    for c in chat:
        print(c.chatting_to.exclude(id=request.user.id))
```

I tried this in the `views.py`. How to get it inside the template now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chatting_to is a ManyToManyField, so one object of Chat has chatting_to many Users

You can use exclude to get all chatting_to users except logged in user,

```
 chat_obj.chatting_to.exclude(id=request.user.id)
```

To get it working in templates, its much easier.

Pass  `{'chats' : Chat.objects.all() }` as context and loop through each,

```
{% for chat in chats %}
    <ul>
        {% for chatting_to_user in chat.chatting_to.all %}
            {% if chatting_to_user != user %}
                <li>{{chatting_to_user.id}}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```